# NodeJS MySQL module can't use two placeholders in a query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to do this, which is exactly as it is in the documentation:

```
get_ids_query = 'SELECT ?? from ?? WHERE stat = 1 LIMIT 10'
```

then I call the function with two values placed inside variables:

```
var name = Table_Names.Tables_PR[t].name
var PK = Table_Names.Tables_PR[t].PK
ids = await this.getIds(PK, name)
```

This is the function:

```
    async getIds(conf1, conf2) {
    return await this.mydb.query(this.get_ids_query, conf1, conf2)
}
```

and these are the logs:

```
        console.log(PK)
        console.log(name)
        console.log(mysql.format(this.get_ids_query, conf1, conf2))
output: idusers
        users
        SELECT `idusers` from ?? WHERE stat = 1 LIMIT 10
```

I've also tried:

```
var name = [Table_Names.Tables_PR[t].name]
var PK = [Table_Names.Tables_PR[t].PK]
```

which logs like this and it still returns the same query:

```
[ 'idusers' ]
[ 'users' ]
query format: SELECT `idusers` from ?? WHERE stat = 1 LIMIT 10
```

What am I doing wrong here? why is it reading the first placeholder but won't read the second one?

Comment: @Akina https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values
this is from the documentation:
var userId = 1;
var columns = ['username', 'email'];
var query = connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE id = ?', [columns, 'users', userId], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});

Comment: Test `mysql.format` described later in "Preparing Queries" - does it works correctly?

Comment: it worked, thanks! I have no idea why it only works like that, but good enough :)